# how to define constants at compile time in clojure

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I want to bake something into my leiningen/uberjar build so that the program prints a particular string that was generated at compile time.

In a C++ Makefile I would use `g++ [...] -D BUILD_VERSION=$SOMETHING`, with `$SOMETHING` being available through my gitlab CI environment, and then use the `BUILD_VERSION` define in my code. Is there a similar way to tell leiningen about this on the command line?

There are several answers here that tell me to read information from the POM file, or the project file. But this information is predefined, but I want to define this in my build script (e.g. use a particular `git describe` command).

Comment: Or this? [How to embed the current git sha in a URL route in Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65496072/how-to-embed-the-current-git-sha-in-a-url-route-in-clojure)